Raspberry Pi Zero WH Hangs on Login
I'm building a "Simpsons TV" with a Raspberry Pi Zero following this guide
I can't get to SSH to modify it further because it hangs on login as seen here
I don't have a keyboard attached to enter the credentials. Is there some other way to get past this? What could possibly be the issue - sd card, power, config files? The guide-maker suggests using 2020-02-13-raspbian-buster-lite with wpa_supplicant.conf, config.txt, and ssh files as seen in the guide.
Thanks so much!

hangs on login - that's not hanging, that's just a login prompt. what actually happens when you try to ssh into the pi? how do you try to ssh into the pi?

You are trying to install a 5 year old OS. Either find something current or search old posts for Buster headless install.
